# matching among multiple variables in R

Tags: r, netcdf

I am beginner in R. So, I am confused about the title of my question. sorry for that. I am trying to explain..

Professor gave me a NetCDF atmospheric data file(18.3MB).this file has 8 dimension and 8 variable. i have to work with 4 variable. every variable`(time,site number,urban site,pm10)` has 683016 data. suppose,

`Urban site number:[2,5]`,

`site number:[1,2,3,4,5,6]`,

`time:[1-3-2012,2-3-2012....]`(hourly data(24) has taken in each day ),

`pm10:[1,2,3,4,5,6.......]`(different for every hourly data with some missing value)

I have to manage this data set only for urban site and 1-3-2012(actually I have to make this spatio-temporal data to spatial data).**I want my final data set like this:**

```
Colum 1(time):  1-3-2012,1-3-2012,1-3-2012,1-3-2012,1-3-2012,1-3-2012

colum 2(Urban site number): 2,2,2,5,5,5

colum 3(pm10 value):1,2,3,NA,4,5,
```

As I only know very basic commands of R so I cant understand how can I solve this problem. Even I don't under stand How can I find any example of this type of problem in internet.

so, please give me some suggestion or link about what I have to learn to solve this problem in R. Please, help me out?

Comment: First you have to read the data. See `ncdf4` package.

Comment: I have used ncdf package for reading data. data is in 1D array form..

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to reshape the dataset but i'm afraid i do not see how your current dataset looks like.

Could you elaborate more on what your dataset looks like right now?

There are packages that help reshaping such as {reshape} or {plyr}. But i need more detail to suggest which one you should use.

Comment: Thank you very much for your concern.As this is a netCDF data file, I don't know to see a full view of this data set.I used ncdf package to retrieve this information:

[1] "file 2012_03_05_PM10_surface.nc has 8 variables:"
[1] "int TMSID[data_num]  Longname:TMSID Missval:-999"
[1] "int TIME[ncl1]  Longname:TIME Missval:NA"
[1] "float PM10[data_num]  Longname:PM10 Missval:-999"
[1] "float urban[ID_LAT_LON,obsnum_urban]  Longname:urban Missval:9.96920996838687e+36"

if you want I can give the full data file..please let me know

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post your inquiries using comments and not answers. You should only provide an answer when you are certain that your answer will solve to the problem.